# Storing arrays with Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In Firebase I have the function `addSubmit` which is meant to submit data `Do the dishes` to an array named `addnote`. However, I do not know how to get the push method to send to an array. My code is below.

```
addSubmit(){
    var self = this;
    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    var getUserInfo = firebase.database().ref('users/' + user.uid);

        if (user){
            getUserInfo.push({
                addnote: ["Do the dishes"]
            });
        }
}
```

My push method winds up giving me several `addnote` arrays instead of placing all strings of `Do the dishes` in the same one. So it looks like:

```
addnote - 'Do the dishes'
addnote - 'Do the dishes'
```

As opposed to:

```
addnote - 'Do the dishes', 'Do the dishes'
```

How would I reorganize my code to make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for:

```
getUserInfo.child("addnote").push("Do the dishes");
```